# Efficient way of storing a large amount of character data between transactions in C++

Tags: c++, optimization, copy, large-data

For our application we have the following scenario:

Firstly, we get a large amount of data (on cases, this can be more than 100MB) through a 3rd party API into our class via a constructor, like:

```
class DataInputer
{
public:
    DataInputer(int id, const std::string& data) : m_id(id), m_data(data) {}
    int handle() { /* Do some stuff */ } 
private:
    std::string m_id;
    std::string m_data;
};
```

The chain of invocation going into our class `DataInputer` looks like:

```
int dataInputHandler()
{
    std::string inputStringFromThirdParty = GiveMeStringFrom3rdPartyMagic(); // <- 1.
    int inputIntFromThirdParty = GiveMeIntFrom3rdPartyMagic();

    return DataInputer(inputIntFromThirdParty, inputDataFromThirdParty).handle();
}
```

We have some control over how the `dataInputHandler` handles its string (Line marked with **1.** is the place where the string is created as an actual object), but no control for what `GiveMeStringFrom3rdPartyMagic` actually uses to provide it (if it's important for anyone, this data is coming from somewhere via a network connection) so we need. As a consolation we have full control over the `DataInputer` class.

Now, what the application is supposedly doing is to hold on to the string and the associated integer ID till a later point when it can send to another component (via a different network connection) provided the component provides a valid ID (this is the short description). The problem is that we can't (don't want to) do it in the `handle` method of the DataInputer class, it would block it for an unknown amount of time.

As a rudimentary solution, we were thinking on creating an "in-memory" string store for all the various strings that will come in from all the various network clients, where the bottom line consists of a:

```
std::map<int, std::string> idStringStore;
```

where the `int` identifies the `id` of the string, the `string` is actually the data and `DataInputer::handle` does something like `idStringStore.emplace(m_id, m_data);`:

The problem is that unnecessarily copying a string which is on the size of 100s of megabytes can be a very time consuming process, so I would like to ask the community if they have any recommendations or best practices for scenarios like this.

An important mention: we are bound to C++11 for now :(

Comment: Sounds like what you need is to *move* the string into the map and then have the class hold a "reference" to the string. ("reference" could be a `string_view` so you keep copy semantics)

Comment: @NathanOliver sorry, I forgot to mention initially we are bound to C++11 for now

Comment: No worries.  You can replace `string_view` with just holding a pointer or iterator to the string as well if you want to keep the default copy semantics.  Moving is a C++11 feature so you still get that performance gain.

Comment: If the goal is to eliminate the copies of `inputDataFromThirdParty`, its feasible, but both `DataInputer::DataInputer` and `dataInputHandler` would have to change to properly push the data through via move-semantics.

Comment: Will not the references to the string go invalid when `DataInputer(inputIntFromThirdParty, inputDataFromThirdParty).handle();` is done and the `dataInputHandler` is done? (method call of a temporary object?)

Comment: Not if you store the string in the map and have the reference point to that.  You'd have to rejigger the work flow a little but that's not a big deal.  Encapsulating it in a `make_dataInputer`function would work nicely.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks, let me see what can I come up with :)

Answer (score 0):

Use move-semantics to pass the 3rd-party data into your `DataInputer` constructor. The `std::move` here is redundant but makes the intention clear to  the reader:

```
class DataInputer
{
public:
    DataInputer(int id, std::string&& data) : m_id(id), m_data(std::move(data)) {}
    int handle() { /* Do some stuff */ } 
private:
    std::string m_id;
    std::string m_data;
};
```

And pass `GiveMeStringFrom3rdPartyMagic()` directly as an argument to the constructor without first copying into `inputStringFromThirdParty`.

```
int dataInputHandler()
{
    int inputIntFromThirdParty = GiveMeIntFrom3rdPartyMagic();

    return DataInputer(inputIntFromThirdParty, GiveMeStringFrom3rdPartyMagic()).handle();
}
```

Of course, you can use a `std::map` or any other STL container that supports move-semantics. The point is that move-semantics, generally, is what you're looking to use to avoid needless copies.

Comment: There is an issue with the DataInputer being constructed as a temporary that immediately goes out of scope when `handle()` returns. That's a different issue than you asked about, however.